# FB login steps clarification

Tags: javascript, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am integrating FB Login in my website. For this purpose I am using Javascript SDK. Here are the steps which I am trying to follow.

1. User clicks on FB Login option, user is shown with POP UP by FB to enter his credentials.
2. FB sends response which includes accessToken, expire time etc.
3. After this user will see registration form dedicated to my website filled with email and other basic entries. He has to just choose some username and then click on signup.
4. As soon as user clicks on signup his details will be stored into DB, his username will be kept in session and he is signed in now.
5. User logs-out. Now, user again clicks on FB Login, if there is email already present in DB I am making the user log into my website by putting his username in session.

Here, are my questions now.

- Shall I also store Access Token for the user in my DB in step 3? If yes then what will be the best encryption medium to send it to server-side?
- Also, is there a need to store access token in cookie/session?
- If answer to my Q1 is yes then will I be able to use the access token stored in DB to validate user if he uses FB Login again?

As far as I know once access token expires Javascript SDK will generate new access token. So, if user logs in after a long time then this validation might not be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

> Shall I also store Access Token for the user in my DB in step 3? If yes then what will be the best encryption medium to send it to server-side?

No, if you are not planning to do any automated tasks for the user with your server. In this case you'd need to change the access token to a long-lived token, but that's another thread.

> Also, is there a need to store access token in cookie/session?

No, Facebook's JS SDK does all the access token handling for you.

> If answer to my Q1 is yes then will I be able to use the access token stored in DB to validate user if he uses FB Login again?

No. You can save the Facebook User ID to your database, which is more constant than the email. Email can change, user id does not. So you should compare the user ID.

#### And just as a side-note:

Facebook also has a server-side login flow that should be used to authenticate the user. If you just use JS SDK to authenticate the user, it would be relatively easy to log in as any user imaginable from the client.

Comment: that means steps which I am following now is correct apart from validating user by UserId instead of email.

Comment: @Gomzee yes, correct in the sense that it'd work. Not correct in the sense that it'd not be secure at all to do login with JavaScript. But ofc depending on your use case the security might not be the first priority.

Comment: login with the js sdk is secure enough. i would always recommend implementing login with the js sdk, it´seasier to handle, you don´t need an annoying redirect and you can refresh tokens without redirect too.

Comment: @luschn yes, if you have a pure client-side application that uses just the Facebook's API. But in this case the "actual" login is done using the javscript, right after the Facebook login succeeds. To another backend.

Comment: what´s your point? usually, the use is already logged in on facebook - if not, it´s just an overlay too, without redirection. and it works as easy with a server, there are many ways to do this in a secure way.

Comment: @luschn The login described here would be to send the user id from the Facebook to some endpoint on the own server with Javascript. The server then checks if there is already a user in the database with that id - if there is, log that user in. This means that I could intercept that login request with e.g. Chrome's dev tools and change the user id to whatever I want, thus being able to log in as any person I want.

Comment: well, if you do it THAT way, then it´s not secure, of course ;)

Comment: what will be the best API to do it on server side with Java.

Comment: @Gomzee I think Facebook officially maintains the PHP SDK, but you can code the login flow quite easily with any language to your server backend. You should check this link for further information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: @Gomzee you basically just redirect user to a certain Facebook's URL -> user performs login -> Facebook directs the user back to your URL with custom `code` -> your server exchanges `code` to a valid `access token` -> Your server checks the user's ID with that `access token` -> Login or direct the user to the account creation

Comment: @jehna1 I tried to follow the link provided by you for manual-build-login-flow and tried to call: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?xxxx&redirect_uri=YYYY  and it gives me following error alert "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."  Any idea why I am getting this alert?

Comment: @Gomzee possibly a subject to whole another stackoverflow question itself, but it states the error quite clearly: You need to go to your app's settings and declare which URLs you want to use as the callback.